# How to deploy SpringBoot app to jboss 7?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jboss

I'm trying to deploy Spring Boot war file to jboss 7. I don't use MongoDB anywhere, but somehow I'm getting NoClassDefFoundError error for MongoClientOptions:

```
16:15:04,876 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-3) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."myapp-0.1.0.war".INSTALL: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."myapp-0.1.0.war".INSTALL: Failed to process phase INSTALL of deployment "myapp-0.1.0.war"
        at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:121)
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1765)
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$ClearTCCLTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:2291)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [:1.8.0_112]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [:1.8.0_112]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [:1.8.0_112]
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error getting reflective information for class org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mongo.MongoAutoConfiguration
        at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.DeploymentReflectionIndex.getClassIndex(DeploymentReflectionIndex.java:70)
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.EEModuleClassDescription$DefaultConfigurator.configure(EEModuleClassDescription.java:144)
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.EEClassConfigurationProcessor.deploy(EEClassConfigurationProcessor.java:100)
        at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:115)
        ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lcom/mongodb/MongoClientOptions;
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method) [:1.8.0_112]
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2583) [:1.8.0_112]
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1916) [:1.8.0_112]
        at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.ClassReflectionIndex.<init>(ClassReflectionIndex.java:57)
        at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.DeploymentReflectionIndex.getClassIndex(DeploymentReflectionIndex.java:66)
        ... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mongodb.MongoClientOptions from [Module "deployment.myapp-0.1.0.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
        ... 13 more
```

My guess - Spring Boot includes it automatically. I've tried to exclude it like this:

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude=MongoAutoConfiguration.class)
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

But it has no effect.

My build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/snapshot" }
        maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/milestone" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.5.7.RELEASE")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
apply plugin: 'application'
apply plugin: 'war'

sourceCompatibility = 1.6
targetCompatibility = 1.6

repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/snapshot" }
    maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/milestone" }
}
dependencies {
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:1.5.7.RELEASE"
    providedRuntime("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat")
}
war {
    baseName = 'myapp'
    version =  '0.1.0'
}
```